# Arrays and Pass-By-Reference

Tags: c++

I am new to coding and need to know how to display the Max, Min, Avg, and the new normalized values of my array. I have the max min and avg working correctly as of now, but am very confused on how i would have my function display the proper new values of the array. The point is to use the function;
xi'=(xi-min)/(max-min)
My current code is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void normalizeMinMaxAvg(double data[], int size,double& min, double& max, double& avg)
{
    max = 0;
    min = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int i;
    avg = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        sum += data[i];
        if ( max < data[i]) {
            max = data[i];
        }
        if (min > data[i]) {
            min = data[i];
        }
    }
    avg = sum/size;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
        data[i] = (data[i]-min)/(max-min);
    }
}


int main() 
{
    double data[] = {-10.0,0.0,20.0,30.0,500.0};
    double min, max, avg;

    normalizeMinMaxAvg (data, 5, min, max, avg);
    cout << "min = " << min << "\n";
    cout << "max = " << max << "\n";
    cout << "avg = " << avg << "\n";
    cout << data;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use a raw array, but `std::array` or `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Strong chance this is school work where those would not be allowed... yet.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan is correct we aren't supposed to be using those yet

Comment: arrays are not passed by value.

Comment: @Michael Dorgan : So? We are not here to support a school curriculum, but to answer questions and provide better solutions (where possible).

Comment: Hence, the 'yet' part.  It's good to point out, but it doesn't necessarily answer his exact question.  You are answering his next year question instead :)

Comment: One little gotcha above - what happens if `min` and `max` are the same?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correctly updating the array values. But to display the array values properly use `for loop` like this:

```
int arrSize = sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0]);
for(int i =0; i<arrSize; ++i)
    cout << data[i]<<" ";
```

Alternatively, you can use the vector instead of a raw array like this:

```
vector<double> data ={-10.0,0.0,20.0,30.0,500.0};
```

And pass it `by reference` to your function.

Comment: Why not simply `for(auto val: data)`?

Comment: Totally agree, but question is tagged under c++ not c++11

Comment: c++11 is the ***current*** standard. So why the distinction?

Comment: @HemantGangwar I think you can assume at least c++14. If the question is tagged C++98, then give a C++98 answer.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Thanks Man will keep this in mind while answering next question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "print out" your array you need to iterate over each member as you have already done several times:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++){
    cout << data[i] << "\n";
}
```

What you are doing currently:

```
cout << data;
```

Will simply print the address of the array.

Comment: Why not simply `for(auto val: data)`?

Comment: @user0042 This depends on the version of c++. Either is fine.

Answer (score 0):

`data` only holds the address of the array, which, in your case, is a pointer to a `double`, you need iterate the array and print out each value individually.